# Automatically open dialpad on incoming / outgoing call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I was thinking of making a small background utility, which detects when either phone receives an incoming call / user makes an outgoing call. Based on the action, the numeric dialpad is displayed automatically when the phone is taken away from the ear.

I know, how to detect the type of call, but then don't know, if it's possible to trigger an Intent action to ask android to open the dialpad programatically.

Pls suggest, if its possible and how.

Thanks
Omkar Ghaisas

Answer (score 1):

yes it is posible create a broad cast reciever liten for incoming call then in onrecieve write down this code it will open a dial pad

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
dial.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
context.startActivity(dial);
```

and for broadcast and services read this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

also check

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html

Comment: But will this open the default numeric pad used for dialing an outgoing number or the one which is shown during the call( when the call is active)? I think it will open a new activity when the call has come in and not open the dialpad when the call is received. Pls suggest.

Comment: hi you have raised a nice point check my updated code it will do the same as you want and i have tested it also

Comment: but your requirement is somehow strange why you want dial pad at the time of incoming call ???
if you dial a number in mid of a call it may cause some problem

Comment: No. I think, I confused you. I want to auto-open the dialpad provided by phonecall activity (com.android.phone.InCallscreen activity I think it is) wherein, if a call is active and user takes the phone away from his ear, the app would open up the dialpad in that activity, else it will pop the dial pad in as it normally is. Let me know, if this makes it clear.

Comment: This seems to be a solution to dial an outgoing number and not automatically display dialpad during an incoming call (when the InCallScreen activity is opened by OS). Pls suggest, if I am wrong.