# Show dialpad on call intent

Tags: android, telephony

I'm starting an outgoing call like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mNumber)));
```

I already know that there is no way of sending DTMF code, so I want the users to be able to punch in the numbers themselves by showing the dialpad. Is there any way to automatically bring up the dialpad after a call? I know that with the ITelephonyClass and

```
mTelephonyService.showCallScreenWithDialpad(true);
```

I can bring up the dialpad, but only if I'm in the app and the call screen is not active. But after firing the intent, the call screen is the active activity, which is why this line of code seems to have no effect. As far as I know, it is also impossible to automatically go back to my app after initiating the call and then calling the aforementioned command.

Is there any way to bring up the dialpad after starting a call?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925076/automatically-open-dialpad-on-incoming-outgoing-call) ?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work... opens up the dialpad but does not initiate the call (the user would have to press the call button him/herself)

Answer (score 0):

You need Action_Dial,

use below code it will open Dialer with number specified as on intent,

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dial_number));
startActivity(dial);
```

Answer (score 0):

use it on your code.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mNumber)));
```